# webapi CORS policy doesn't work with Kestrel server as a localhost

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I tried many ways to jQuery.ajax() post from localhost:44381 to my webapi at localhost:44333, I got a CORS error as below.  Could you help?

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44333/api/answer' from origin 'https://localhost:44381' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

I researched many posts and only by specifiying of the Access-Control-Allow-* in the web.config of the webapi project got me closer the endpoint, but still failed. All other approaches got me "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" error.

web.config

```html
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
    <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />-->
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I've tried specifying the CORS policy in the web api's startup.cs and the ajax options in the javascript, but none of them works.  They are all commented out for your reference.

Startup.cs

```js
public IConfiguration Configuration {
  get;
}
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  .......
  services.AddCors();
  //services.AddCors(options =>
  //{
  //  options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder =>
  //                    {
  //                      builder.AllowAnyMethod()
  //                            .AllowAnyHeader()
  //                            .AllowAnyOrigin();
  //                            //.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
  //                            //.SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()

  //                            // The specified URL must not contain a trailing slash (/)
  //                            //.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44381")
  //                            //.AllowCredentials()
  .......
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
  .......
  app.UseRouting();

  //app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
  app.UseCors();

  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();

  .......
}
```

form.ts

```js
let apiBaseUrl = 'https://localhost:44333';
let apiController = 'answer'
let thisUrl: string = apiBaseUrl + '/api/' + apiController;

function jQueryAjax() {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: thisUrl,
      data: JSON.stringify(postBackModel),
      headers: {
        //  'RequestVerificationToken': antiForgeryToken,
        //  'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      //xhrFields: {
      //  withCredentials: true
      //}
    }).done(function(result) {
        ........
      }
```

Comment: But the error is "the response was not OK". What status code are you getting in response to your OPTIONS?

Comment: Also, you did set up CORS on the correct server, right?

Comment: That was the error message showed up in the browser's Developer Tools.  I set a breakpoint at the first line of the AnswerController's [Post] method, but it was not hit at all.  So there is no further status code to show.

Comment: What does it look like the the Network tab of the dev tools,; you see the OPTIONS request; thats' the cors preflight

Comment: Are you referring to the launchSettings.json for the WebAPI at the localhost? When done debugging, I just push the WebAPI project to IIS.  I am not aware of other CORS needs to be set up at the IIS server.  Could you point me to the server settings I need to set?  Thank you.

Comment: Ah.  The network has 401 preflight status.  I commented out the xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true} in the ajax option because it was not working and not allowed if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is *.

Comment: This is where it gets complicated.. At its most basic, the server that responds to the fetches from the script is the one that needs to put the CORS headers; I can see you've got two servers, essentially - one at localhost:44381 that is serving the site, page, script etc, and one at localhost:44333 that is serving up your API.. If these are the ony servers that exist then it's the 44333 one that needs to add the CORS headers. If you've got some (an)other server in between the script and the api, that is responsible for the CORS, then it needs to go there...

Comment: It's not un heard of to have e.g. Kestrel serving an API, but there being an IIS in between Kestrel and the browser, doing SSL, CORS, whatever.. Suffice to say whenever the script from the browser talks to what it thinks is the back end, some server along the way (be there one or more) has to add CORS headers to the responses going back to the script from the API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238074/discussion-between-user266909-and-caius-jard).

Comment: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check` do you enable Windows Authentication with your site/app?